# Scanning for user input in MATLAB or Octave (when writing a .m file)

Tags: matlab, user-input, octave

I'm rather new to MATLAB and I'm having a bit of difficulty. I want to ask the user for input and I seem to be able to do that fine when coding line-by-line in the terminal. However, I want to save my code in a *.m* file so that I may print it and have it graded. Here lies the problem. It appears to me that the program is not waiting for user input, but rather jumping to the next line of code and tries to use the next line of code as though it was input to the program, which is obviously not what I want. How can I stall the program to make sure it waits for user input rather than trying to use my code as input?

I should probably mention that I'm not using MATLAB, but I'm using GNU Octave instead, which is an open-source alternative to MATLAB with the same syntax.

Here's my not-so-completed code:

```
% Get user input
time_slots = input('Desired number of time slots: ')
packet_length = input('Desired length of packet train: ')
%probability = input('Desired probability of packet arrival: ')

% Fill a vector of length 'time_slots' with uniformly-distributed random numbers
P = rand(time_slots,1);

% Determine if packet was recieved or not.
for i = 1:time_slots
    if P(i) <= probability
        Q(i) = 1;
    else
        Q(i) = 0;
    end
end
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
>>>Desired number of time slots: Desired length of packet train: time_slots = [
](0x0)
>>>error: invalid conversion from real matrix to real scalar
error: octave_base_value::int_value (): wrong type argument 'matrix'
error: rand: expecting integer arguments
>>>
```

Also, when I run the program with just the user input lines, I do not get an error. However, it does not assign my input to the correct variable (it assigns it to `ans` instead. See below: [image: Screenshot of result without any additional code]

Comment: The `input` command will wait for the user to input. I pasted the first line of your code (containing `time_slots`) in a .m file which I have and the program doesn't execute unless I input some value. What do you exactly mean when you say program tries to use next line as input. It cannot proceed unless you give it some input (in this case, a number, not an alphabet/string, for that you have to use option `'s'`.)

Comment: I mean it appears to not be waiting for my input. I've edited my question with the error message I'm getting.

Comment: Also, I tried it without the rest of my code and It gives me no error, however, it's still not waiting for my input. So when I input a number, it assigns that value to `ans` rather than any of the three variables I declared.

Comment: This code works as expected for me (Octave 3.8). Have you got something confusing like a variable named `input` in the base workspace or another script named `input.m` on the path?

Comment: No I've got none of that. I should also mention that I'm using QtOctave as well, which is just a GUI frontend for Octave. I've updated the question with a screenshot showing that.

Comment: Type `which input` into your command window and report what it says. It should indicate that it is using a built-in version of the function and give the path.

Comment: Wild guess: something between the frontend and Octave is messing with line endings or somesuch. What happens when all the statements are terminated with semicolons?

Comment: @Notlikethat: Seems plausible. I'd suggest also adding a blank line or even a dummy function/operation in between (e.g. `abc = 1;`).

Comment: @Notlikethat, The same thing happens with the semicolons

Comment: @horchler Still no luck. I inserted `a=1' between all the lines. I'm gonna see what happens without the gui

Comment: nevermind...see next comment

Comment: So I had a `%` in front of the third line on accident. Removing it solved some of my problems. However, the frontend is still assigning my input to `ans` rather than the desired variables

Comment: Got it! The frontend has two options. "send to octave" and "run". I was clicking on the former, which caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it for any people in the future.

First, I removed the unnecessary `%` from my code. Then I made sure to hit the correct button in QtOctave as shown below (correct button is circled in green, wrong one is crossed out in red):

[image]